# Why is the default router always loaded?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I make 3 pages and navigation menu. After click on menu punk page is reload.

tpl:

```
<a (click)="toLogin()">Login</a> |
<a (click)="toHome()">Home</a> | 
<a (click)="toCatalog()">Catalog</a>       
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

component:

```
toLogin() {
  location.href = '/#/login';
  location.reload();
}

toHome() {
  location.href = '/#/home';
  location.reload();
}

toCatalog() {
  location.href = '/#/catalog';
  location.reload();
}
```

In result i get not SPA application, bun on angular. Routing is worked OK.

Problem is follow:
After build make and deploy, user has no opportunity walk on pages. Router always redirect to default address

router:

```
imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginViewComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeViewComponent },
    { path: 'catalog', component: CatalogViewComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }
  ], { useHash: true })
],
```

Please help fix routing for build.

[LIVE DEMO is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-ftisxw)

Important: i need reload page after every click on menu

Comment: Why you are not using `routerLink`(https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) for the navigation?

Comment: There is a reason) 
I need to reload the pages for my custom widgets.

Comment: Okay, you got the answer and remember that you are making single page application, so your widgets should initialized when component loads.

Comment: @KirkLarkin navigation is not worked on BUILD

Answer (score 0):

You should use routerLink:

```
<div class="container">
    <a [routerLink]="['/login']" (click)="toLogin()">Login</a> |
    <a [routerLink]="['/home']" (click)="toHome()">Home</a> | 
    <a [routerLink]="['/catalog']" (click)="toCatalog()">Catalog</a> 
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And click event use to trigger function for some other purpose.

Comment: Thanks, but i need reload page after every click

Comment: On every route change you inject component to view,and refresh it,add ngOnInit() and console.log something,every time you switch to it ,console.log will be called.